# Adding an element from a list to a random row in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, random

I am in the process of creating a 'random meal selector' from a number of recipe books. The objective is to use this to select what I have for dinner on each day of the week. I've created a dictionary for 'meals' that I've converted to a pandas df, and a list for 'days'. Here is a sample:

```
meals = {'Recipe': ['Chicken Kebab', 'Chicken Balti', 'Chicken Stir Fry', 'Chicken Curry', 'Cola Chicken', 'Chicken Fajita Pie',
                    'Chicken in Black Bean Sauce', 'Stuffed Meatballs', 'Pesto Pasta'],
         'Book': ['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', '3', '1', '1'],
         'Page': ['48', '50', '52', '58', '72', '74', '80', '87', '108'],
         'Category': ['Normal', 'Curry', 'Asian', 'Curry', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Asian', 'Pasta', 'Pasta']}

df = pd.DataFrame(meals)

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
```

What I'm looking to do, is randomly apply each element of the list to a new 'day' column in the dataframe, so it's selecting which recipe I make on each day. How would I go about doing this? Down the line I want to create some rules e.g. There can only be one Category 'Curry' selected, so any assistance with that would be great too! Quite new to Python so appreciate all the help you can provide.

Comment: There are only 4 distinct categories so which 4 days should be assigned. It's also unclear how days should be chosen. Multiple values per day? Only 1 per day? Are there guarantees that there won't be more than 7 categories if unique choices or is cyclic selection necessary?

Comment: You should use np.random and fill the columns with integers. Then replace each integer with one of your categories.

Comment: To apply your criteria for curry and others, you can write your rules on integers using using known criterias  like odd-even, prime, sqrt, mod, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I've added another while loop to make sure the number of recipes = the number of days + the number of blanks/nextweeks/your choice of usage.

Removed the if len(days) = 0 as this will not matter now.

Added a shuffle of the days list. (This is important because you have duplicate value of "Next Week") so the first recipes have a higher probability of being selected as "Next Week", since there are more "Next Week"s than Mon/Wed/etc. (comment out the shuffle to see)

```
meals = {'Recipe': ['Chicken Kebab', 'Chicken Balti', 'Chicken Stir Fry', 'Chicken Curry', 'Cola Chicken', 'Chicken Fajita Pie',
                    'Chicken in Black Bean Sauce', 'Stuffed Meatballs', 'Pesto Pasta'],
         'Book': ['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', '3', '1', '1'],
         'Page': ['48', '50', '52', '58', '72', '74', '80', '87', '108'],
         'Category': ['Normal', 'Curry', 'Asian', 'Curry', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Asian', 'Pasta', 'Pasta']}

df = pd.DataFrame(meals)

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

print (df)
mealdays = []
while len(meals['Recipe']) != len(days):
    days.append("Next Week") #"Blank", " ", "Nothing"
while len(meals['Recipe']) != len(mealdays):
    day = random.choice(days)
    #put an if statement here for your future condition. i.e if Curry already chosen etc.
    mealdays.append(day)
    #the below is to make sure you have atleast one meal per day, and then if you have more than 7 recipes which you do, you will have another set of days to chose from
    days.remove(day)


random.shuffle(days)

df['Days'] = mealdays
print (df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have more meals than there are days and not explained how you would use them so I improvised for you.

```
meals = {'Recipe': ['Chicken Kebab', 'Chicken Balti', 'Chicken Stir Fry', 'Chicken Curry', 'Cola Chicken', 'Chicken Fajita Pie',
                    'Chicken in Black Bean Sauce', 'Stuffed Meatballs', 'Pesto Pasta'],
         'Book': ['1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '1', '3', '1', '1'],
         'Page': ['48', '50', '52', '58', '72', '74', '80', '87', '108'],
         'Category': ['Normal', 'Curry', 'Asian', 'Curry', 'Normal', 'Normal', 'Asian', 'Pasta', 'Pasta']}

df = pd.DataFrame(meals)

days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

print (df)
mealdays = []
while len(meals['Recipe']) != len(mealdays):
    day = random.choice(days)
    #put an if statement here for your future condition. i.e if Curry already chosen etc.
    mealdays.append(day)
    #the below is to make sure you have atleast one meal per day, and then if you have more than 7 recipes which you do, you will have another set of days to chose from
    days.remove(day)
    if len(days) == 0:
        days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

df['Days'] = mealdays
print (df)
```

Your conditions goin foward should be implemented using the commented out if statement.

Comment: What if I only wanted one iteration of each day in the df? The idea is it plans meals randomly for a single week, so there's only 1 Monday in a week, only one meal should show as Monday, the rest would be another day of the week or blank. How would I do this?